Is there a way to simultaneously change password for numerous user account simultaneously in IBM AS/400?
I am new to IBM AS400. Recently there is a need in my company to implement a 90 days password change for all users. The problem is some users won't change their password even if we already notify them in advanced (notify through email or from AS400 itself). The first option is to have a QSECOFR account that would change the password automatically. The second option is to set PWDEXP value to *Yes and wait for the password to expire and it would notify the user to change. I am trying to mitigate if somehow the users were not able to change their password individually and would require someone else. Now imagine that there are 100 of user who needs to recover their account and using a super admin would require to manually change the password one by one. My question is can you change or recover the password of the user simultaneously?

Is this an actual programming-related question?

It is more on the configuration for AS400.

Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]. SO is a Q&A website for programming-related questions

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://serverfault.com/

In principle, I agree that this question is probably better suited to Server Fault, but (1) the IBM midrange tag seems to be barely established there (which I realize is a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem), so for better or for worse, it will get more eyeballs here, and IBM midrangers tend to dabble in both programming and admin; and (2) there is a gray area where server config problems might be best handled with some programming. This question is plausibly welcoming programming solutions, though I will grant that if that is what is being sought, then the text could make that more explicit.

Alright thank you for the feedback. I will be sure to try the server fault.

Who on earth comes up with regular password changes in 2024? It has been well established in the last few years as not enhancing security because lazy users try to evade this harassment by using the minimum changes to a once established password to satisfy the technical checks.

@PoC unfortunately, every security team on the planet. Momentum is a hard thing to counteract.

@PoC - I don't know your definition of "few", but this has actually been known for what I'd consider a long time. Individual experts have questioned the practice of mandatory periodic password changes since at least 2006, if not earlier. Actual research debunking the effectiveness of periodic password changes started showing up by 2010. By 2015, governmental cyber security organizations were officially recommending against such password changes. So yeah, well established.

And @jmarkmurphy is right - pretty much everyone still believes in mandatory periodic password changes. Most are not aware that organizations like the FTC (2016), NIST (2017), and Microsoft (2019) have published official recommendations against the practice. And even some who are aware, still believe they know better.

I'd say it's not even so much the momentum (though that is undoubtedly a big factor). It's the intuitiveness of the idea that changing passwords should be more secure than not changing them (until known to be compromised). People are much more comfortable sticking with what makes sense to them.

Put 90 into system value QPWDEXPITV like this, from the AS400 command line,
chgsysval sysval(QPWDEXPITV) VALUE(90)

= = =
From the AS400 command line type,
WRKSYSVAL SYSVAL(*SEC)

Shows you all the system values related to security.
Look through them and you will see the above system value whose description is "Password expriation interval". Setting it to 90 means the passwords on the system have to change every 90 days. There is also system value QPWDEXPWRN, default 7 , this is the number of days before the password expires the AS400 will start warning the user.
Hope that helps.
The way to switch it off again is
chgsysval sysval(QPWDEXPITV) VALUE(*NOMAX)

